# Google Chrome extension to edit local HTML files like in MS Word

Tags: html, google-chrome-extensions

I have saved several web pages on my local HDD. Is there any GC extension that can highlight text, change text color, editing just like in MS Word? Mainly need WYSIWYG feature. I don't want to use MS Word since when opening the .htm file, Word tent to change some html tags, after saving the changes, the web page will become broken (css or missing tags) in browser.

I can do editing in Chrome Developer Tools (ctrl+shift+i) and save the web page overwriting it. And see the change by pressing F5. Or using Visual Studio to do highlight and bold, however, I just that's too much. Hope there is an easy solution to this.

Comment: May be you can try `document.body.contentEditable="true"` in Chrome DevTool Console? This allows you directly edit on the Web Page.

Answer (score 1):

There are several online editors that will provide what you need - some of them have a Chrome extension or "app". Try [ShiftEdit](https://shiftedit.net) for example - search for it in the Chrome Web store.

Comment: This is a good tool. However, it's online editor, meaning I have to upload my LOCAL file again and save the file on ShiftEdit's server. I might lose offline reading capability when no internet access. These are my concerns.

Comment: If you want to do this offline, why Chrome at all? Depending on your OS, there's a slew of HTML editors that offer syntax highlighting. Some are even free. Notepad++ on Windows, TextMate or TextWrangler on the Mac, and Eclipse on pretty much everything.

Comment: Not syntax highlighting. I want to add some notes to the HTML content itself. Bold or highlight some text, that's why I mentioned WYSIWYG tool in my question.

Answer (score 1):

A Chrome extension is not going to be the best approach.

Although there are some extensions that enable Chrome to save to local files, they rely on launching a separate web service to modify files, and you have to edit files from source code, CSS or JavaScript inspector, no WYSIWYG.

Also beware of Chrome Extensions that, like ShiftEdit, are just a link to a service on the web that is not going to work offline.

---

I'm going to recommend an article with many links to free and paid editors for Windows, Mac and Linux. Filter the ones that are for Windows and free first (and are still alive), and give them a try:

> [Smashing Magazine: 25 Useful WYSIWYG Editors Reviewed](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/05/06/25-wysiwyg-editors-reviewed/)

My recommendation from that article are Amaya, NVU and Kompozer.

Also, another one that isn't listed there is [Trellian](http://www.trellian.com/webpage/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source local files editor for Chrome: [Sympathy Editor](http://captnemo.in/sympathy/)